# Jest specs in nested directories

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs

Using vue-cli and the template "webpack", I get an out-of-the-box setup for unit testing VueJS components.

As long as I keep components source in `src/components/` and their tests in `test/unit/specs/` everything is fine. However when i nest them in directories (ie. `src/components/fields/` and `test/unit/specs/fields`) Jest seems to ignore some of them.

I'm also getting different outputs by using the flag `--no-cache`.

Is there additional config needed for getting sub directories to work with Jest ?

Comment: I fixed the --no-cache issue by adding `resetModules: true` in config

Comment: What does your jest config look like? Particularly what about the 'testMatch' property?

Comment: Turns out I simply need to use --no-cache cli option